# Passing Firebase Admin App in to Data Access Objects

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I'm trying to create data access objects that can be unit tested using the local Firebase emulator. The objects will be used from Firebase functions and use the Admin SDK.

To do this I need to pass in the Firebase app object but the type for this is different between firebase-admin and rules-unit-testing packages.

DAO Object

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

class MyDaoRepo implements IDaoRepo {
    readonly app : firebase.app.App;
    readonly store : firebase.firestore.Firestore;

    constructor(app : firebase.app.App) {
        this.app = app;
        this.store = this.app.firestore();
    }

    async getAll(ids : string[]) :Promise<DocumentSnapshot> {
        const refs = ids.map((id)=>{
            return this.store.doc(COURSE_COLLECTION+'/'+id);
        });

        retrun this.store.getall(...refs);
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
import * as test from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import { MyDaoRepo} from "../../dal/my-dao-repo";

describe('constructor', () => {

  it('get data from ids', 
    async () => { 

        const app = test.initializeAdminApp({projectId: 'my-test'});

        const dut = new MyDaoRepo(app);

        ...
    });
    
});
```

In Function Use

```
    ...

    const app = admin.initializeApp();

    const myDao = new MyDaoRepo(app);  <<=== This fails saying it is not the same type and is missing properties

    ...
```

How do I get a type for App that can take both the test app and the production app types?

I'm new to Firebase and Typescript so guess that I'm missing a import but can't find any examples doing the same.

The actual error produced when assigning the test 'App' to production 'App' type is

`Type 'App' is missing the following properties from type 'App': instanceId, machineLearning, projectManagement, securityRules ts(2739)`

Comment: Have you tried using a [Union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) of the test and production app types? It would be nice to have the actual error too.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try however I'n thinking it might just push the problem further down the line as now found that the test firestore type is missing getAll() method too and other types look to be the same but different too

Comment: I've found that there is an environment variable I can set to make the testing instance use a different server. FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 will hopefully point the tests to the local emulator.

Comment: Hi, may I know if you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: @Happy-Monad no we ended up having to build our model objects around "firebase-admin" and we will need to duplicate them for the other firebase SDK unfortunately. The union just pushed the issue deeper.

Comment: @DavidRitchie do you might if I ask sample code how you solve this issue?